# Nx e2e folder structure

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

Before anything, I am not very savvy to e2e.

When I create a component/feature Nx creates a e2e folder inside the apps folder.

I am a bit concerned with the organisation of my apps folder, it can grow into uncontrollable proportions if for every lib component I create the e2e folder goes into the apps folder.

As per design the apps folder is executable, I understand that and makes sense.

My question is. Is it possible to perhaps change the path of the e2e folders are being generated?

```
apps/
  admin-store
  public-store
  ...

e2e/
  admin-store-e2e
  public-store-e2e
  shared-ui-comp1-e2e
  shared-ui-comp2-e2e
  shared-ui-comp3-e2e
  ...
```

I find this a much cleaner approach than having all of the `executables` in the apps folder.

Thank you

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to replace the default generated folder name with your own e.g. `e2e`. If yes then you can do it in `cypress.json` just add there e.g. `"integrationFolder": "cypress/e2e",`

more info read in [official docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files)

Comment: I was looking more for like when I generated a lib / app it would automate into that folder, but thank you for your comment :)